# Hibernate session.get() shows null

Tags: java, hibernate, null

Although I read session.get null problems on stackoverflow and tried to do what they suggested, my problem seems to continue.

```
SessionFactory mysessionfactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
Session mysession = mysessionfactory.openSession();
mysession.beginTransaction();

Myperson person3 = (Myperson) mysession.get(Myperson.class, 3);
System.out.println("there you go : "+person3.getName());
```

As simple as it seems, i am just trying to retrieve data from database. Let me show you the database.

[image]

As you can see above , the data i like to retrieve has a name !

[image]

This is what i get, NOTHING ! 
And finally , i run the code with debug mode and i hope you'll understand the problem and suggest a solution.

[image]

i am in a conflict here, my database shows that data which has UserId of 3 has a name  but why can't i see it in my output ?

EDIT : Here is my hibernate xml file as you requested.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM 
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

 <hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>

      <property name="hibernate.dialect">
        org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
      </property>

      <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">
        com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
      </property>

      <property name="connection.pool.size">1</property>

      <property name="hibernate.connection.url">
        jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myhibernatedb
      </property>

      <property name="hibernate.connection.username">
       root
      </property>

      <property name="hibernate.connection.password">
       000003
      </property>

      <property    name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>

      <property name="show_sql">true</property>

      <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

      <!-- List of XML mapping files -->

      <mapping class="org.emreverim.com.Myperson"/>
      <mapping class="org.emreverim.com.Vehicle" />
      <mapping class="org.emreverim.com.FourWheeler" />
      <mapping class="org.emreverim.com.TwoWheeler" />

    </session-factory>
  </hibernate-configuration>
```

EDIT 2 : here is myperson class as you requested.

```
@Entity
public class Myperson {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)   
    private int userID;     
    private String name;    


    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private Collection<Vehicle> vehicle = new ArrayList<Vehicle>();


    public Collection<Vehicle> getVehicle() {
        return vehicle;
    }
    public void setVehicle(Collection<Vehicle> vehicle) {
        this.vehicle = vehicle;
    }

    @Lob
    private String description;
    @Temporal (TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date joinedDate;


    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
    public Date getJoinedDate() {
        return joinedDate;
    }
    public void setJoinedDate(Date joinedDate) {
        this.joinedDate = joinedDate;
    }
    public int getUserID() {
        return userID;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setUserID(int userID){

        this.userID = userID;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you share your hbm mapping file, and Myperson class

Comment: try doing it without transaction , or if you want the transaction to exists , before calling the person.getName() , call the mySession.getTransaction().commit()

Comment: @Cyril , i did share hbm mapping file and Myperson classs.

Comment: What's the sql do you get in the console?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem here is caused by the fact that Hibernate ***[Session.get() method](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Session.html#get(java.lang.Class,%20java.io.Serializable))*** expects a `Seriliazable id` object, which is not provided in your case here `mysession.get(Myperson.class, 3)` .

Because the given value `3` here is of primitive type `int` which contains only the value and isn't serialized so you have to use **new Integer()** method in order to pass an `Integer` serializable object or **new Long()** to pass a `Long` serializable object to the `get()` method, so just change:

```
Myperson person3 = (Myperson) mysession.get(Myperson.class, 3);
```

To:

```
Myperson person3 = (Myperson) mysession.get(Myperson.class, new Integer(3));
```

Or:

```
Myperson person3 = (Myperson) mysession.get(Myperson.class, new Long(3));
```

Answer (score 1):

We happened to see the solution, my database has been configured as utf-16 while it should have been utf-8. so its just as simple as that. i gave thumps up for all answers, thanks for all of your concerns.

Answer (score 0):

In your entity map you forgot to add the annotations @column attributes to the field and @table to link it to the table.

Example:

```
@Column(name="description")
private String description;
```

Check this example for the annotations http://archive.oreilly.com/pub/a/onjava/2007/02/08/an-introduction-to-hibernate-3-annotations.html?page=2